# How to Unit test a JDialog with Cancel and Ok button

Tags: java, junit, jbutton, jdialog

I am trying to make a jUnit test that tests the popup of the jDialog and the buttons that are associated with the jDialog. I think that I have the understanding and code written to make sure that the jDialog is not null, but I am unsure as to how to test the buttons. I am thinking that I would not have the jUnit test to allow for the dialog to pop up and I have to click one of the buttons. I assume that the test needs to run and do everything without me click anything. I have played around with the doClick(), but every time I try to use asserts I get errors in my code. How would I approach testing the buttons?

The jDialog class is:

```
    public class ExitDialog {

    JDialog exitDialog = new JDialog();
    JLabel textDisplay = new JLabel("<html> You are about to exit the Application! <br> Are you sure you want to proceed? <html>");
    public JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton acceptButton = new JButton("Yes");


    public void exitDialog(){

        //sets up the dialog
        exitDialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        exitDialog.setVisible(true);
        exitDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        exitDialog.setSize(270,110); 
        exitDialog.setTitle("Exit Confirmation");


        //adds the text and button to the dialog
        exitDialog.add(textDisplay);
        exitDialog.add(cancelButton);
        exitDialog.add(acceptButton);

        //closes the dialog pop-up
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                exitDialog.dispose();
            }
        });


        //Closes the application and then saves the current state
        acceptButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //need to make a save call here so if they do accept to close the application then auto saves the current edits

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is what I have so far for my testing of the jDialog. This current is passing the jUnit test which is just checking to make sure that my dialog is not null.

```
public class ExitDialogTest {

    private GUI.ExitDialog guiExitDialog;



    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        guiExitDialog = new GUI.ExitDialog();
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        guiExitDialog = null;
    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link GUI.ExitDialog#exitDialog()}.
     */
    @Test
    public final void testExitDialog() {
        assertNotNull(guiExitDialog);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Test
    public final void testExitDialogCancel() {


    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe something like this, as Oracle says: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html This class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed. The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of Java platform implementations.

Comment: Because you ask for a **Unit test** I've to answer that this is not a unit test you want to create but an integration/gui test. With a unit test you test the functionality of one unit which is typically a method but you only have the constructor, nothing more (and two anonymous ActionListener you cannot access).